# Filter results by date in timestamp field

Tags: php, mysql, database, timestamp

I have already had some help but not sure why this isn't working.

I am trying to use a form to let a user filter their activity (which is stored in a DB)

My code:

```
$_GET['from'] = '01/11/2013';
$_GET['to']   = '25/11/2013';

$from = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_GET['from']);
$to   = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_GET['to']);

$sql = "
    SELECT * FROM transfer 
    WHERE personID = $user AND DATE(time) BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'
";
$sql = sprintf($sql, $from->format('Y-m-d'), $to->format('Y-m-d'));

print_r($sql);
```

This prints
`SELECT * FROM transfer WHERE personID = 84587749 AND DATE(time) BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-14'`

When I query this in PHPmyadmin it shows the record, however not showing in my page?

Comment: Did you run a query and loop through and display the results?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what this means?

Comment: You need to print these results out.

Comment: But first run a query, and then fetch results, then print them.

Comment: Sorry again, im still not sure how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL looks fine but you don't appear to have issued the executed the SQL query in the database and retrieved the results?? Maybe I'm missing something but you need to connect to your database:

```
class DBi {
  public static $mysqli;
}

DBi::$mysqli = new mysqli('servername', 'database', 'password', 'user');

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
  die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Then you need to perform the query:

```
$result = DBi::$mysqli->query($sql) or die ("Unable to execute SQL command:".$sql);
```

And finally, retrieve and use the result:

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row["fieldname"];
```

Comment: I have done this, it is above this code i just didnt paste it on here

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you print out your results.

```
$dbserver = "localhost";
$dbname = "nameofDB";
$dbusername = "username";
$dbpassword = "password";

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

$query = "SELECT * FROM transfer WHERE personID = 84587749 AND DATE(time) BETWEEN ? AND ?";

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){

    /*
    Binds variables to prepared statement

    i    corresponding variable has type integer
    d    corresponding variable has type double
    s    corresponding variable has type string
    b    corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets
    */

   $to = $_POST['to'];
   $from = $_POST['from'];

   $stmt->bind_param('ss', $from, $to);


   /* execute query */
   $stmt->execute();

   /* Get the result */
   $result = $stmt->get_result();

   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Configure this how you want to print out each row.
        echo 'Details: '.$row['details'].'<br>';
        echo 'Time: '.$row['time'].'<br>';
        echo 'Balance: '.$row['balance'].'<br>';
        echo '<br><br>';
   }

   /* free results */
   $stmt->free_result();

   /* close statement */
   $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: This is because you need to change Col_1, Col_2, ... to the columns in your table.

Comment: I have, `echo 'details: '.$row['details'].'<br>';
        echo 'time: '.$row['time'].'<br>';
        echo 'balance: '.$row['balance'].'<br>';`

Comment: sorry, does need need to replace my code or add to it? and sql

Comment: right, this is now showing the row. The only thing is, the to and from fields should come from a form on a previous page?

Comment: Yeah, that's right... the variables will show up like this, if done correctly `$_POST['to'];` and `$POST['from'];`, if you want I can update my answer using that?

Comment: If you could that would be fantastic!!

Comment: Updated my code and it is showing nothing now? Not sure if this helps but this is the url `/filter_activity.php?from=01%2F10%2F2013&to=14%2F10%2F2013`

Comment: Can you help any further?

Comment: Sorry, just came out of a meeting, try using `$_GET['to']` instead of `$_POST['to'];`... but you really should be submitting your form as a POST, instead of GET.